# Swing, Java GWT, Servlets (Web Application)

Tags: java, swing, servlets, gwt

I am in a serious confusion since this morning after the project meeting .. I am very much new to java, I have worked as Application Supporter before, but java seriously ruffled my mind.

My Question: I am developing a web based application using Servelts/MYSQL, and my boss wants me to develop another application which was already developed before and he has lost the code, I have to develop that app again, But I don't want to use servlets for my 2nd project.. I think I can do that application using Swing or GWT, or AJAX, now that problem is have to integrate my application with my first application. How to covert Swing application to Servlet app, I am worried a bit. Your help and suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: If you use GWT or AJAX, you will still be using Servlets. Swing is used to create desktop apps, not web apps, so it's not possible to create a Swing app, and use it in a web app. You seem very confused about what all these tchnologies are, maybe you are not the best person to choose what you will use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't convert a Swing application to a web application, at least not in an easy way.

An option would be to create your 2nd application as an Applet, that way you could use Swing and you could integrate it fairly easily into your web application.

There is another option:
[Deploy and run Java Swing applications in browser by automatically converting them to HTML/JavaScript.](http://www.creamtec.com/products/ajaxswing/solutions/swing_in_browser.html)
This is however not a free service/solution and I can't give further advice on this.

But since you have to rewrite the 2nd app from start (which you wanted to do using Swing), you'd better do that as a webapp as well, and then you will have no problem integrating it into your first application.

GWT is already very similar to Swing (you can create GWT apps mostly using Java code, it uses components called widgets, panels, events and event handlers) so if you create your webapp using Google GWT, it will be easy to do your 2nd app too.

Comment: My first application is already in Servlets , Is it possible i can use GWT and integrate ?

Comment: Yes, you can start using GWT in an existing project.

Comment: Thank you so much , I will start building my second project in GWT.. and integrate that in my first project that is in servelt. I hope it should work .